# Jquery - Check a checkbox and change background color of div

Tags: jquery

So I've been researching for a while, and I'm kind of stumped.  What I'm doing is pulling data from a database and putting it into rows of divs.  What I want to do is make the div "clickable" and have the background color change when clicked.  I will have a hidden checkbox element that will be toggled.   Here is the code I've been able to find to assist me so far.

What I need to do is figure out where to add a function that toggles the class whether the checkbox is checked or not.

**Jquery**

```
$('.item').click(function(){
     $('.item').toggle(
         function(event) {
            $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
         },
         function(event) {
            $(this).find('input').attr('checked', false);
         }
     );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
   stuff here 
   <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="item1" value"true">
</div>

<div class="item">
   stuff here 
   <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="item2" value"true">
</div>
```

Comment: ...and is this working or not?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the correct method for all boolean attributes is `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: Please supply some HTML markup for further clarification of your issue.

Comment: @DevlshOne As of 1.6, actually. And `.prop()` is not just for "boolean", but all DOM element properties. @ OP this thread will give you more insight on when to use `prop` and `attr`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.item').click(function(){
     var $this = $(this), $chk = $this.find('input:checkbox'), checked = $chk.is(':checked');
     $chk.prop('checked', !checked);
     $this.toggleClass('checked', !checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mxMPQ/)

Comment: This is working, I was forgetting something basic.  Thank you very much!